# Soft Input Panel does not change back from NumericPin mode

Tags: win-universal-app

I am unable to get the Soft Input Panel (SIP) or Touch Keyboard to switch back to the standard text keyboard after setting the InputScope of a PasswordBox to NumericPin.  This happens both when I put the controls on the same page as well as when I put the controls on two separate pages.  Once I have navigated to the page containing the PasswordBox with the NumericPin InputScope, the Soft Input Panel will not respect the InputScope setting on any other TextBox controls.

Put this code into a Page in a UWP app and you'll see what I'm talking about:

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBox.InputScope>
            <InputScope>
                <InputScope.Names>
                    <InputScopeName NameValue="SearchIncremental"/>
                </InputScope.Names>
            </InputScope>
        </TextBox.InputScope>
    </TextBox>
    <PasswordBox x:Name="PinPasswordBox" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <PasswordBox.InputScope>
            <InputScope>
                <InputScope.Names>
                    <InputScopeName NameValue="NumericPin"/>
                </InputScope.Names>
            </InputScope>
        </PasswordBox.InputScope>
    </PasswordBox>

</StackPanel>
```

Note that I tried this in two separate pages with the first page containing the TextBox and the second containing the PasswordBox.  In that scenario, the Soft Input Panel correctly shows the SearchIncremental keyboard.  However, once I navigate to the page with the PasswordBox, the keyboard stays in NumericPin mode until the app is restarted.

Has anyone else seen this problem?  How can I make the keyboard behave as expected?

Comment: I guess this issue is a bug with the UWP PasswordBox control.  Any idea where we can submit an issue like this to the Microsoft UWP controls dev team?

Comment: Ran across this yesterday and have been googling without any solution.  Were you able to report this somehow?  Seems like a pretty significant bug!

Comment: I went ahead and reported it here.  Please upvote the issue. https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/14810244-passwordbox-with-inputscope-numericpin-locks-keybo

Comment: Thanks. I added my upvotes.